# SameSite cookie property lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies, samesite

[**Updated** - see comment at end]

Google will be changing the behaviour of its Chrome browser so that cookies will no longer work when hosted in another domain's IFRAME unless the cookies are explicityly set to SameSite = None, and Secure.

To this end, we made this change in our ASP.NET MVC code.  We have some logic around when to set this (only for partners that we've agreed to work with), so we have this conditional logic:

```
if (isSameSiteCookieEnforced)
{
    cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    cookie.Secure = true;
}
```

We tested this in our DEV, QA, STAGE environments and it works perfectly.  In Chrome's developer tools (Application > Cookies), you can inspect the cookies and see that they are all marked as Secure, and have None in the SameSite column.

However, when we rolled this to our PROD environment, we get different results using the same browser: the cookies are marked as Secure, but the SameSite value is empty.

What we checked:

- Load Balancer: we isolated this and navigated direct to a single web server, same result
- Installed .NET frameworks: in all environments, we've installed 4.7.2 and 4.8
- Addressed .NET framework: in all environments, the web.config stipulates 4.7.2
- Code: we retrieved the relevant DLL from PROD and inspected with ILSPY.  It contains the above code

Currently at a bit of a loss to explain how the cookies could lose the "SameSite" property.  Navigating to **chrome://flags** and filtering on **SameSite** we're showing the three settings to be "default", so Chrome shouldn't be affecting anything differently from one environment to another.

**Update**

Our ASP.NET MVC application uses an IHttpModule and as one of the last steps in the EndRequest method we trace out the cookies.  You can clearly see that they are set with SameSite=None and Secure=true.  But, when they arrive at the browser, the SameSite property has been stripped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - turned out that we were missing a Windows patch.

Comment: what Windows patch was missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are conditioning on whether the new SameSite behavior is enforced, you will want to test the behavior with the chrome://flags entries same-site-by-default-cookies and cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure set to both "Enabled" and "Disabled". If they are set to "Default", there is no way to tell what the behavior is. It could be on or off, depending on the random seed determined on startup, since the features are currently in a fieldtrial (A/B testing) on Beta. See the second bullet list in "Launch Timeline" here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

Comment: @chilly - I'm not testing whether this is enforced or not by the browser.  We have server-side business rules which stipulate when to set SameSite=None & Secure=true (see code snippet in original post).  We trace when this is executed (not shown).  I see the trace message confirming the server set these properties in STAGE and PROD, but the browser shows: Stage = SameSite=None&Secure; Prod = SameSite={blank}&Secure.

Comment: How is isSameSiteCookieEnforced computed?

Comment: How isSameSiteCookieEnforced is, I think, irrelevant, but we've verified it's working correctly.  At the very end of the ASP pipeline, just before the Response is returned, we trace out the cookies and we can see that they are all set as expected.  I'll add this to the original post.

Comment: When you said "we get different results using the same browser", did you mean that you're literally using the same instance of Chrome, or you're using two instances of Chrome with the same version number? Like I said above, the flags should be set to "Enabled" or "Disabled" to guarantee the behavior, because "Default" can mean either (depending on the fieldtrial configuration, which can differ on different devices).

Comment: The other thing is: if you're seeing a discrepancy in what your server thinks it sends out on the wire vs what the browser thinks it sees, it may be helpful to capture a log of all the network activity and examine the request/response headers. See https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug#TOC-Using-a-NetLog-dump